# Split fix monthly value to days and countries based on revenue shares

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0958a30759b4913375127f41eba45d6d)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    country VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    sales_volume INT,
    fix_costs INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(country, sales_date, sales_volume, fix_costs
)
VALUES 

("DE", "2020-12-01", "500", "0"),
("NL", "2020-12-01", "320", "0"),
("FR", "2020-12-01", "350", "0"),

("DE", "2020-12-02", "700", "0"),
("NL", "2020-12-02", "420", "0"),
("FR", "2020-12-02", "180", "0"),

("DE", "2020-12-03", "0", "0"),
("NL", "2020-12-03", "0", "0"),
("FR", "2020-12-03", "0", "0"),

("None", "2020-12-31", "0", "2000");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
sales_date   |   country    |   sales_volume   |     fix_costs
-------------|--------------|------------------|------------------------------------------
2020-12-01   |     DE       |       500        |     37.95  (=2000/31 = 64.5 * 0.59)
2020-12-01   |     FR       |       350        |     26.57  (=2000/31 = 64.5 * 0.41)
2020-12-01   |     NL       |       320        |      0.00
-------------|--------------|------------------|------------------------------------------
2020-12-02   |     DE       |       700        |     51.32  (=2000/31 = 64.5 * 0.8)   
2020-12-02   |     FR       |       180        |     13.20  (=2000/31 = 64.5 * 0.2)  
2020-12-02   |     NL       |       420        |      0.00
-------------|--------------|------------------|------------------------------------------    
2020-12-03   |     DE       |         0        |     32.26  (=2000/31 = 64.5 * 0.5) 
2020-12-03   |     FR       |         0        |     32.26  (=2000/31 = 64.5 * 0.5)    
2020-12-03   |     NL       |         0        |      0.00
-------------|--------------|------------------|-------------------------------------------
```

---

In the result above I want to split a `fix_cost` value per month `(in this case 2000)` to the country `DE` and `FR` **per day** based on the **daily** `sales_volume` in **each** of the selected `countries`. So far I have used the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997226/exclude-certain-values-when-splitting-a-fix-value-to-countries-based-on-a-daily?) which worked perfectly:

```
SELECT
    sales_date, 
    country, 
    SUM(sales_volume),
    (CASE WHEN country <> 'NL'
        THEN SUM(SUM(fix_costs)) over(partition BY year(sales_date), month(sales_date))
            / day(last_day(sales_date)) 
            * SUM(sales_volume)
            / SUM(CASE WHEN country <> 'NL' THEN SUM(sales_volume) ELSE 0 END) over(partition BY sales_date)
    END) AS fix_cost_per_day
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

---

However, as you can see in the data on `2020-12-03` there are no sales at all. 
Therefore, the query above is not able to split the daily `fix_costs` to each country on this day. 
To solve this issue I want to modify the query so in case there is a day without a `sales_volume` the values should be split **50/50**.

How do I have to modify the query to achieve this?

Comment: Where does the data come from on the third day?

Comment: The monhtly value is 2000 and I divide this value by the days of the month. In the case above this is 31 since it is December. Therefore, 64.5 is the value that needs to be assigned to each day of the month. This daily value now gets assigend to each country based on the sales_volume per day. If there is no sales_volume for the countries it should be divided 50/50.

Comment: I don't see how you get to your expected result no country has a sales_volume on 2020-12-03 in the sample source data so where have you conjured the sales_volume figures in your expected result for 2020-12-03?

Comment: For a date without any sales_volume I want to split the daily value of 64.5 to each country 50/50. Therefore, it is 32.26 for DE and FR in the example above.

Comment: Put another way your expected result bears no resemblance to the sample input..even ignoring the fixed costs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you. want to allocation 2,000 by each day of the month and for all the countries other than `'NL'`.

This is arithmetic with window functions:

- Use `last_day()` to get the number of days in the month.
- Use window functions to calculate the proportion of revenue for each country other than `'NL'`.
- Use conditional logic so `'NL'` is special.

As a `SELECT` query:

```
select s.*,
       (case when country = 'NL' then 0
             else ((2000 / day(last_day(sales_date))) *
                   sales_volume / nullif(sum(case when country <> 'NL' then sales_volume end) over (partition by sales_date), 0)
                  )
        end) as imputed_fixed_costs
from sales s
order by id;
```

Note:  The `2000` makes the code clearer, but apparently you can input this into the query using:

```
from sales s cross join
     (select sum(fix_costs) as fixed_costs
      from sales
      where country = 'None'
     ) f
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05cb17760e923575767a5ea13e459cdc) is a db<>fiddle.

This is easily incorporated into an `update` if you really want to change the data, although the example query in the question is a `select`.

To handle months with no sales:

```
select s.*,
       (case when country = 'NL'
             then 0
             when sum(case when country <> 'NL' then sales_volume end) over (partition by sales_date) > 0
             then ((2000 / day(last_day(sales_date))) *
                   sales_volume / nullif(sum(case when country <> 'NL' then sales_volume end) over (partition by sales_date), 0)
                  )
             else (2000 / day(last_day(sales_date))) * 1 / sum(country <> 'NL') over (partition by sales_date)
        end) as imputed_fixed_costs
from sales s
order by id;
```

Comment: When I run the DB-Fiddle I get 0 for 2020-12-03 but it should be 32.26 both for DE and FR. Those countries have no sales valome therefore I want the daily value of 64.5 to be split 50/50 to each country.

Comment: @Michi . . . That is really just a small tweak to the query.

Comment: Just for my documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=85ad5998e7cee7796223efd4c3ca0f43